# how to hot deploy spring mvc without restart tomcat?

Tags: spring-mvc, hotdeploy

i want to know spring-mvc how to do hot deploy,and when i add a controller or action without restart tomcat.
For example,i have a Controller named "testDataController",and i add a action named "test".i want to see the laster view without restart tomcat